# Munkres Problem: Define a $C^{\infty}$ map $f: \mathbb{R}^9 \to \mathbb{R}^6$ such that $O(3)$ is the solution of $f(x)=0$.

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

On Munkres's book analysis on manifold chap "the boundary of manifold", question 3, says: let $O(3)$ the set of orthogonal matrices, as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^9$.

a) define a $C^{\infty}$ map $f: \mathbb{R}^9 \to \mathbb{R}^6$  such that $O(3)$ is the solution set of equation $f(x)=0$.

What does it mean?

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand the question? If you say precisely what's causing you trouble, you'll be more likely to get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify $\Bbb R^9$ with the set of $3\times 3$ real matrices and $\Bbb R^6$ with the set of symmetric $3\times 3$ real matrices. Then,
$$f(A)=AA^{T}-I.$$

Comment: Sorry, but R^9 different from R^6.  I don't understand!!

Comment: @Jianluca The point is that $f(A)=AA^T-I$ is always symmetric, i.e. $f(A)^T=f(A)$. But the set of symmetric $3\times 3$ matrices has only $6$ independent coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

A $3 \times 3$ matrix is orthogonal iff its columns $c_1,c_2,c_3$ satisfy the six relations $$c_i \cdot c_j = 0 \quad (i < j), \qquad c_i \cdot c_i = 1 \quad (i=1,2,3).$$

This lets us express an element of $O(3)$ precisely as an element of the kernel of the map $M_3 \cong \mathbb{R}^9 \to \mathbb{R}^6$ defined by $$(c_1,c_2,c_3) \mapsto (c_1 \cdot c_2,\,c_1 \cdot c_3,\, c_2 \cdot c_3,\,c_1 \cdot c_1 -1,\, c_1 \cdot c_1 -1,\, c_2 \cdot c_2 -1,\,c_3 \cdot c_3 - 1).$$

You can express each of the coordinate functions as a map $\mathbb{R}^9 \to \mathbb{R}$ which, as it involves only addition and multiplication, is clearly smooth. For example, writing $c_i = (x_i,y_i,z_i)$, the first coordinate function is $x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2$.